# Grey cross / red cross to delete text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to add to my website possibilty to clear a div (delete all text).
A grey cross on the left fo the div, when you click, div is cleared. But when mouse is over, like on stackoverflow.com (in the comments), cross become red.
How can I do that ?

HTML :

```
print $cgi->div({-id=>"subheader"},$cgi->span({-id=>"reset"}));
```

CSS :

```
#subheader {
        text-align:center;
        clear: both;
        margin: 3px 0 10px 0;
        height:18px;
        background: #f4f4f4;
        color: #808080;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#reset {
        float:left;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
}
```

Where do I put images ? in CGI or CSS ?
Thanks

For example with these images :[image: close]
black when mouse over, grey if not.

Comment: In the future, note that your PHP or Perl (or whatever that is) is irrelevant and harmful to your question. That is not your HTML. Your HTML is what that produces and is what the browser sees. View source on your page and copy/paste your _actual_ HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the images in CSS:

```
#reset {
    background:url('grey-cross.png');
}
#reset:hover {
    background:url('red-cross.png');
}
```

[EDIT]

OP also asks how to make it a link so it works with JQuery.

It doesn't necessarily need to be a link element (ie an `<a>` tag) to work with JQuery; it can be any HTML element. You just need to put a click event onto it using JQuery:

```
$('#reset').click(function() { ...your code here... }
```

However, semantically, it's best if you use an element type which is appropriate to the action it will perform, so I'd suggest making it a `<button>` or something similar. But the JQuery code is much the same whether it's a `<button>` or a `<div>` or anything else.

Hoep that helps.

Comment: And how to make a link, so when I click, Jquery delete all inner HTML ?

Comment: You could also turn it into a sprite to save on the number of objects loaded and just move the background-position on hover.

Comment: @Paul - a very good suggestion. It would have added complication to the answer though; I was trying to keep the answer reasonably simple. But that would be a good enhancement for the OP to try if he wanted to improve it further.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 things for this:

1. the javascript that detect the click and deletes the text of the element
2. css to change the image:

   ```css
   #reset{backgroud-image:url('image.jpg');height:20px;width:20px}
   #reset:hover{backgroud-image:url('image2.jpg')}
   ```

Comment: but where to put the <a> tag, so with jquery I can delete inner HTML of #subheader ?

Comment: @eouti here edited it for you. for the js use something like <div id="reset" onclick="remove()"></div>

Comment: @eouti for jquery use $('#subheader').empty()